# What does おくびにも出さず in this sentence?

Tags: words

I'm trying to figure out what does the おくび　mean in the following sentence:

私の汚れたところを、おくびにも出さず、綺麗にしてくれる人

For context, a character is thanking another person for helping them out after they've puked.

Jisho is telling me that おくび　means belch or burp, but I'm still not too sure how I can interpret this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Exchage! Not sure if this help, but in Jisho's examples there is 「おくびにも出すな」 translated as "Don't breathe a word of it to anyone", so 「おくびにも出さず」seems to mean they won't say anything about what happened? Does it make sense in the context?

Answer (score 2):

Here, [おくびにも出さない](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8F%E3%81%B3%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82%E5%87%BA%E3%81%95%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) is a common idiom that means "not to breathe a word" or "not to reveal one's (negative) feeling at all".

The idiom is worth memorizing, but おくび ("burp") is a rare word, and it's almost never used on its own at least in modern Japanese. I believe most Japanese speakers do not even know what おくび means.